# External Keyboard Space Key Somehow Changed to Another Key

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on a thinkpad W540 laptop. I have a multi monitor setup that I haven't used in a few months and now when I try to plug my external keyboard into my laptop to operate my multi monitor setup the external keyboard space key is not working as a space anymore. I think it is acting as a right click because it opens up the menu when I am in gnome terminal.

Note that my laptop keyboard doesn't have this issue, it is only my external usb keyboard that I plug into my laptop that has this issue.

Here is the output of `xev` when I press space on my laptop keyboard and my external keyboard.

**Laptop keyboard when pressing space**:
Key code = 65
[image]

**External keyboard when pressing space**:
Not sure what all this means
[image]

I have a dual boot with Arch linux and Ubuntu and I have the same problem on both distros. Both were fine several months ago or so. So not sure if there has been some update or something that changed things, but will great to get my external keyboard working properly again if anyone has an idea what might be happening?

UPDATE:

Output of `xinput -list`
[image]

The keyboard is [Dell Keyboard KB212-B](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/12/shared-content~solutions~en/documents~ce_doc_kb_kb212b_kb4021_us.pdf)

Comment: what's the keyboard model? can you add the output of `xinput -list` (while the external kbd is attached)?

Comment: @quixotic Sorry for the delay - I added the information to my post.

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but did you test another external keyboard with it just to confirm that you don't have an issue with the keyboard itself?

Comment: @DarrenHaynes cut-n-paste the text instead of screenshots please, it's much more readable (and searchable).  indent each line with 4 spaces to get a code-block or see the [editing help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).  thanks!

Comment: @Buck  My embarrassment is great. No I hadn't tried another keyboard since I didn't have one, and figured since the keyboard was just sitting around for a few months that it was some sort of linux update or something that maybe the cause. I just tried a keyboard at my wife's school and it that one is working fine. Sorry to be a time waster having made such an assumption :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's my answer.  Do you need your sign, LOL

It happens to the best of us. In all my years of troubleshooting computers, I developed a sense of where to start looking and where to go next.  I always check the plug on computers that "don't come on".  I got paid to travel over  200 miles on an emergency run to press the power button on the monitor of a computer one day.

> I hate to ask the obvious, but did you test another external keyboard
>   with it just to confirm that you don't have an issue with the keyboard
>   itself? – Buck 17 hours ago